# Error editing neovim config. E79: Cannot expand wildcards; plugins not working

Tags: configuration, neovim

When I open my init.vim,  I'm met with this error message repeated many times

**E79: Cannot expand wildcards**

My neovim config file is stored: *~/.config/nvim/init.vim*

And vim does not respond to my plugin commands,which have been installed via a plugin manager.

:help e79 returns:

```
Cannot expand wildcards 

               
                                                                         
A filename contains a strange combination of characters, which causes Vim to
attempt expanding wildcards but this fails.  This does NOT mean that no
matching file names could be found, but that the pattern was illegal.
```

The current contents of my init.vim:

```
set number
set scrolloff=16
set relativenumber
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab 
set smartindent
colorscheme koehler 
 au TextYankPost * silent! lua vim.highlight.on_yank {higroup="IncSearch", timeout=500}

call plug#begin('~./config/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim'
call plug#end()

let mapleader = " "
nnoremap <leader><CR> :so ~/.config/nvim/init.vim<CR>
vnoremap <leader>yy  "+y 
nnoremap <leader>pf :Files<CR>
```

Error messages when using plugin keywords:

```
E492: Not an editor command: Files
```